# How to put javascript variables into an HTML table from a separate Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, electron

So I am trying to get used to Electron. I have an HTML table set up, and in a separate js file I have variables that are taken from a form for the user. I need to figure out how to put these variables into the html table.

here is html :

```
<script src="./index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="add.js"></script>

<font size="3" face="Courier New">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name of Item</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Purchase Amount</th>
    <th>Sold Amount</th>
    <th>Platform Sold</th>
    <th>Total Fees</th>
    <th>Total Profit</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here is html file for the form:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column col-10">
      <h1 class="text-center">New Sale</h1>

      <form id="todoForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="add-input">Name of Item</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="add-input" placeholder="Jordan 1..." id="itemName">
          <label class="form-label" for="add-input">Size</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="add-input" placeholder="Large..." id="size">
          <label class="form-label" for="add-input">purchase Amount</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="add-input" placeholder="$160..." id="pAmount">
          <label class="form-label" for="add-input">price Sold</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="add-input" placeholder="$400..." id="sAmount">
          <label class="form-label" for="add-input">platform Sold</label>
          <input class="form-input" type="text" name="add-input" placeholder="StockX..." id="platform">
        </div>

        <button class="btn">Add Sale</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <script src="./add.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

and here is javascript file:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

var itemName = document.getElementById("itemName");
var size = document.getElementById("size");
var pAmount = document.getElementById("pAmount");
var sAmount = document.getElementById("sAmount");
var platform = document.getElementById("platform");
```

All help is appreciated!

- I am omitting some pieces of the files to save space

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

**HTML CODE**

```
  <tr>
    <td id = "name"></td>
    <td id = "size-cell"></td>
    ...
  </tr>
```

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = itemName.value;
document.getElementById('size-cell').innerHTML = size.value;
```

Comment: Hedge Where does the document.getElementbyID go?

Comment: logically it should go after this `var platform = document.getElementById("platform");`

Comment: is something wrong with the html form? and getting the inputs from there and turning them into variables?

Comment: Html seems fine.. is your table already present while the form is open? and have you put the id's for the table cells?
The table needs to be present on the DOM when you run the piece of code from my answer.

Comment: i'm sorry for the dumb questions - what you do mean by present when the form is open? Do you mean when the application is running?

Comment: check this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/9zoucxn0/
enter all fields and press the button

Comment: Hi, try to teach the `document.querySelector`, it's the most common used and most versatile way to select DOM-elements dynamically.

Comment: @AmoghHegde Ok, yours works great. But when i copy it over it still does not. I feel like it has something to do with referencing the js , using the <script>. what's the proper format there?